# Alternative to html5 output tag?

Tags: html

I made a page using a form with few input "number".  I used the html output tag to display the result.  But in MSIE, the calculations were performed, but the output tag would not display them.  Is there a simple workaround or alternative?  It works if i use an input tag in place of the output tag, but then the result is displayed in a box which doesn't format very nice.  (I thought the solution would be rather simple, like: (-"I have variableresult apples." - )

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 output tag is not supported on [IE (or EDGE)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp). So you are stuck with using input tag. You can, however, always use CSS to fix the layout of your screen.

If you want to support IE, you would have to go the old fashion way i.e. use JS with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Output tag is not supported by MSIE or Edge according to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp), a solution using Javascript can be found [here](http://html5doctor.com/the-output-element/). Additionally you can just use CSS to style the output-input as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I write a code might helps you, because I didn't clear with your question.

```
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = parseInt(a.value) + parseInt(b.value)"> 
   <input name="a" type="number" step="any"> +  
   <input name="b" type="number" step="any"> = 
   <output name="o"></output>
</form>
```

I made simple calculator.

OUTPUT tag will not support in IE.